# Problema em implementar o método atualizar no Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Estou usando banco de dado MongoDB. Acredito que a maioria entende que para atualizar um registro é de extrema importância pegar a chave identificadora, ou seja, o **_id**, estou conseguido obter a chave identificadora do registro fazendo dessa forma;

```
ngOnInit() {
    const codigoLancamento = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];
 }
```

Porém não tenho ideia de como o meu método receberá esse registro através do método logo abaixo;

```
onSubmit(){
    var id;
    this._restaurantAdminService.editRestaurant( id , this.restaurant).subscribe(
      response => {
        if(!response.restaurant) {
          this.status = 'error';
        } else {
          this.status = 'success';
          this.restaurant = response.restaurant;




        }
    },
      error => {
        var errorMessage = <any>error;

        if(errorMessage != null){
          this.status = 'error';
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Estou aberto a quaisquer dúvidas que precisem para me ajudar a resolver esse problema.

Comment: Tenta  this.codigoLancamento = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];

Comment: Ai no metodo onSubmit(){
    const id=this.codigoLancameto;

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber quem é que fica me perseguindo e notificando minhas postagens com negativo como está lá em cima do topo, que filho da mãe para não dizer outra coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o único proplema é considerar "const codigoLancamento" como uma variável de escopo de `ngOnInit`. Essa variável tinha que ser do escopo do component, para você acessa-la no submit.

```
codigoLancamento;

ngOnInit() {
    this.codigoLancamento = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];
}

onSubmit(){
    var id = this.codigoLancamento;
    this._restaurantAdminService.editRestaurant( id , this.restaurant).subscribe(
      response => {
        if(!response.restaurant) {
          this.status = 'error';
        } else {
          this.status = 'success';
          this.restaurant = response.restaurant;




        }
    },
      error => {
        var errorMessage = <any>error;

        if(errorMessage != null){
          this.status = 'error';
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: já tentei dessa forma, não funciona.

Comment: no submit, se você der um `console.log(this.codigoLancamento)` imprime o valor correto?

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado valeu mesmo, eu tinha feito um outro código feito por mim que dava 15 linhas de código, então você economizou 15 linhas de código kkkk